# Is there any difference if I grab or destroy the mask?

Tags: far-cry-4

One of the things to collect are mask of a serial killer. You can grab or destroy them. Does it make any difference to the reward?

EDIT:

Now that I've found 3 mask, I have the impression it is just that some mask can't be destroyed (can't fire underwater for example) and so must be grabbed, and other must be destroyed because they are too far away to be grabbed, if anyone can confirm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, it's confirmed. Destroying the masks counts as much as collecting them. This could've saved me a ton of time. Those hard to find ones would've just met molotovs, grenades, rpgs and the like just to give me a reason to spend money on ammo to empty my wallet.. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score -1):

Im not 100% sure about this myself either. I was at the northern most part of the middle map section (had to use a buzzer to even get there). I was inside a cave with prison cells and shackles. Two guys were down a small stairs area and I heard the mask humming so I know I was close. If you already captured the nearest bell tower then you will see this location as the camera pans to the near by spots. Anyway I tossed a grenade into the hole and got the multi kill but I never noticed the karma or any other notification. All I know is the humming stopped and the blue map area notification went away. So I guess you're right.